# Is it possible to operate a VM using Azure Functions managed ID?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to operate a VM using Azure Functions managed ID?

I used a service principal to write code to operate a VM from my PC.

```java
    /**
     * Main function which runs the actual sample.
     *
     * @param azure instance of the azure client
     * @return true if sample runs successfully
     */
    public static boolean runSample(Azure azure) {
        final String rgName1 = "rgName";
        final String linuxVMName = "vmName";

        try {

            VirtualMachine virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines().getByResourceGroup(rgName1, linuxVMName);

            System.out.println("Running Command");
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
            commands.add("whoami");
            commands.add("touch /tmp/tmp.txt");

            RunCommandInput runParams = new RunCommandInput()
                    .withCommandId("RunShellScript")
                    .withScript(commands);

            RunCommandResult runResult = azure.virtualMachines().runCommand(virtualMachine.resourceGroupName(), virtualMachine.name(), runParams);

            for (InstanceViewStatus resopnse : runResult.value()) {
                 System.out.println("code : " + resopnse.code());
                 System.out.println("status : " + resopnse.displayStatus());
                 System.out.println("message : " + resopnse.message());
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("final");
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Main entry point.
     *
     * @param args the parameters
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // Authenticate
            String clientId = "XXXXXXXXX";
            String domain = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            String secret = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            //MSICredentials credentials = new MSICredentials();

            AzureTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

            Azure azure = Azure
                    .configure()
                    .withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
                    .authenticate(credentials)
                    .withDefaultSubscription();

            // Print selected subscription
            System.out.println("Selected subscription: " + azure.subscriptionId());

            runSample(azure);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would like to modify some of this code to run on Azure Functions.

Is it possible to operate a VM using an Azure Functions managed ID without using a service principal?

Comment: What do you mean `managed ID`? Is that you want to use MSI?

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge.

We would like to use the managed identity listed in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#using-the-azure-cli

I recognize that the above is the equivalent of Managed Service Identity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will do a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to use MSI to use Azure VM run command feature in Azure Function. If so, please refer to the following steps

1. [Enable Azure MSI in Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
   [image]
2. Assing Azure RABC role to the MSI.

Running a command requires the `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action` permission.  The **Virtual Machine Contributor** role and higher levels have this permission.

[image]

3. Code. I use the package `com.microsoft.azure:azure:1.38.0`

```
String subscriptionId="";
        AppServiceMSICredentials appServiceMsiCredentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        Azure azure = Azure
                .configure()
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
                .authenticate(appServiceMsiCredentials)
                .withSubscription(subscriptionId);
        final String rgName1 = "testlinux_group";
        final String linuxVMName = "testlinux";
        try {

            VirtualMachine virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines().getByResourceGroup(rgName1, linuxVMName);

            System.out.println("Running Command");
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

            commands.add("echo 1");

            RunCommandInput runParams = new RunCommandInput()
                    .withCommandId("RunShellScript")
                    .withScript(commands);

            RunCommandResult runResult = azure.virtualMachines().runCommand(virtualMachine.resourceGroupName(), virtualMachine.name(), runParams);

            for (InstanceViewStatus res : runResult.value()) {
                context.getLogger().info("code : " + res.code());
                context.getLogger().info("status : " + res.displayStatus());
                context.getLogger().info("message : " + res.message());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("final");
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It was successful in my environment as well.